# Checking PHP Smarty templates Cache

Tags: php, caching, smarty

i am using Smarty templates latest build 3.1.15. I wanted to enable templates caching and it works. I can see the templates created in the cache directory.
However, whenever i want to check if there is a created cache file using the is_cache() method i get

`php
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Call of unknown method 'is_cached'. <-- thrown in .... sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 819`

I just want to check if there is a cache using

`echo (!$smarty->is_cached('home.tpl','home')) ;`

and i display the cache by

`$smarty->display('home.tpl','home');`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For later versions of Smarty this method has actually been renamed to `isCached()`. Try that instead.

This method hasn't been `is_cached()` since Smarty 2. [isCached() API Docs](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.is.cached.tpl).